# include/execute JS before emailing blade template

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.4

Is is possible to include and execute (before sending an email) javascript code within the blade template?

The problem is that I need to email users some images, which are generated on the fly by a 3rd party program. I got them with an AJAX request. So what I have by the moment is something like:

```js
//report.js

$(document).ready(function() {
    //Retrieving the GPS data
    $.getJSON(url + user_id, function (response)  {
        //...get and shows the images on <tbody>
    });
});
```

```html
@extends('template.user_theme.template')
@section('user_content')


    <center>

        <h3>
            <b>Report</b>
        </h3>

        <div id="data">
            <table id="images_table">
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </center>

@endsection

<script src="{{ asset(".../report.js") }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But this is not working. 
The email reaches the user without the images, which means that JS was never executed? Or could there be another issue?

Is it possible to achieve something like this?
Is there any other approach?

Comment: no its not possible this way. You have to fetch the images using your backend and include them in template directly.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is executed by the client (i.e. the browser) so no, I don't think it is possible.

But as you did in JavaScript, you can call the service from PHP and pass the image info to the blade template.

Comment: Or is it any chance to attach (within the html template file) the JS url so it could be executed at the client browser?

Comment: Most email clients don't allow JavaScript execution by default. So I suggest you looking for some other way.

Comment: I already did... I had to transfer all the load to the server, but it worked... Thanks